# How do I limit the max supply of a MultiversX NFT collection?

Tags: blockchain, multiversx

I'm currently working with the MultiversX blockchain, and I've successfully registered a new NFT collection & created an NFT following the [documentation example here](https://docs.multiversx.com/tokens/nft-tokens/#example-flow).

However, I need to limit the amount of NFTs that can be created for a specific collection. The documentation says:

> The ESDT manager can stop the creation of an NFT for the given ESDT forever by removing the only ESDTRoleNFTCreate role available.

So I guess I could just create the max supply of a collection (`e.g` 100 NFTs for collection1) and then remove the creation role. But this means I have to create all NFTs beforehand, which is not ideal.

1. Is there another way to limit the max supply, maybe when registering/issuing the collection itself?
2. On a separate note, is there good documentation on the difference between EGLD / ESDT / SFT / NFT. I'm particularly interested in SFTs, but I don't understand how the state change from fungible -> non-fungible works (e.g. once the SFT becomes non-fungible, is it stuck in that state or can it become fungible again?). Documentation on that is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no optional "limit supply" for an NFT collection.

   After you created the collection and give the `ESDTRoleNFTCreate` to your address or a contract you can call X time the function mint.

   Eventually, if you use a SC to mint the NFT, you can set a variable to limit the maximum allowed mint.
2. You can't convert NFT in SFT or SFT in NFT.

   The only operation allowed is converting an SFT into Meta-ESDT with no way back. This is possible only because SFT are really close to META-ESDT but with no decimals :)